# how I can determine if the div have an overflow hidden using html?

Tags: html, angular, wep

How can I determine if `div` has `overflow` `hidden` using **html** ?
using `Ngif` I don't want to use it in type script code I need to set another attribute if the `div` has `overflow hidden` .

```
<div id="greetings" [innerHTML]="page.title">
</div>

#greetings{
   width: 100 px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Exist a way to get the style information about of element by using a var inside of element in this case is named `#vars` it has the ability to get the style directly in the element that's why I put the atribute `style="overflow: hidden"`

Take a look to the following example:

```
<div id="greetings" style="overflow: hidden" #vars>
  <div *ngIf="(vars.style.overflow === 'hidden')">
      Hello universe!
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kryzwt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Its already hidden ! Or its just return true if there are text hidden !!
I mean When this condition return true !!  *ngIf="(vars.style.overflow === 'hidden')

Comment: if you change `style="overflow: hidden"` to for example  `style="overflow: auto"` it will disappears, it is just an example I just giving you how you can compare the style properties in **html directly**

Comment: I need just to determine if div has overflow
I mean it has title and hide the overflow of it , becouse there are case the div contain full title